# vue-class-component syntax with typescript

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

The example on https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component (for the component syntax that's new in vuejs3) but I'm using straight type script instead of babel. I therefore tried:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue"
import Component from "vue-class-component"

@Component({
    props: {
        propMessage: String
    }
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    helloMsg = "Hello, " + this.propMessage

}
</script>
```

Unfortunately, `this.propMessage` can't be found. How do I have to change the syntax to make it found?

Comment: Despite the tag, this question is not related to _vuejs3_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess `this.props.propMessage` would work (but i can't test it right now) and you may have already tried.

I recommend you using `@Prop` decorator from [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) which provide a clearer syntax on the long-end.

It would give something like :

```
@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    @Prop() propMessage !: string;

    helloMsg = "Hello, " + this.propMessage;
}
```

Good luck